# How can I remove value of particular row using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

If I clicks add button the new row gets created. If I have 3 rows and I want to remove 2nd row value using remove button.

When I clicked on remove button, then row is removed but the value of last row index gets removed by default.

I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/287/

```
<td >
  <input type="text" name="count" class="form-control2" autocomplete="off" id="langlistNumber_{{$index}}">
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="count" class="form-control3" autocomplete="off" id="langlist_{{$index}}"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="count" class="form-control3" autocomplete="off" id="langurllist_{{$index}}">
   <a href ng-click="removelanglist(index)" ng-if="displayremovebutton">Remove</a>
</td>

$scope.addlanguagelist = function() {
     debugger;
     var index = $scope.languagelist.length;

     console.log(index);
     $scope.isCollapsed = true;
     $scope.displayremovebutton = true;
     $scope.languagelist.push({
        "model.urlListNumber": "",
        "model.numbersUrlList": "",
        "model.url": "",
        "index": $scope.countBlocks
     });

     $timeout(function() {
         $scope.countBlocks++;
     }, 200)};

     $scope.removelanglist = function(index) {
            console.log(index);
            $scope.languagelist.splice(index, 1);
     };
```

Comment: try using my proposed solution which works as per your expectations and check the demo in linked jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/288/) that removes an item for you.

The updated remove function uses the item that is passed from the template and find index of that item in the array. That index is then used with splice method as mentioned below:

```
$scope.removelanglist = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.languagelist.indexOf(item);
    $scope.languagelist.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly I want

Answer (score 0):

Swicth:

`ng-click="removelanglist(index)"` to `ng-click="removelanglist($index)"`

Comment: Yes I have changed but i works like same. if i click remove button of second row, last row gets deleted.

Comment: Same thing does not happen to me. Tried this on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Texj/290/)